# Extract Month from Date Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I currently have a date field with the format `01 January 2022, 04 February 2022` Etc

I am trying to create a column that pulls out the month in MMM format (JAN, FEB)

Using `Month = Month('Current Week'[Created On])`

This pulls the numbered date of the month (1,2)

I tried to add in format but this does not work as Month only allows 1 argument.
What else can I do to pull out the month format that I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Month String = 
UPPER( 
    FORMAT( 
        DATEVALUE('Current Week'[Created On]),
        "mmm"
    )
)
```